# Conditional IF Statement in Excel, Change Other Cells According to Content

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to make a revision timetable for myself on Excel.

Let's say I'm doing four exams, A to D. Each exam has a certain number of "practice papers" that I have to do. Below is a demonstration table on Excel:

```
ExamName     NoOfPapers
ExamA        4
ExamB        5
ExamC        7
ExamD        1
```

There is another table, with two columns: MonthDate and the paper I want to practice on that da. So,

```
 May         Paper?
 1
 2
 .
 .
 .
 29
```

I want to make it work so that if I put ExamA in the field under `Paper?`, it would automatically deduct 1 from the NoOfPapers of ExamA, to make it 3, so I make sure I'm not repeating the paper too many times.

If I only had 17 papers, it would have been easy to do it manually. But unfortunately I have 99 papers to do (exactly 99 :P).

How can I implement this on a cell as an IF statement (or any other possible way) on Microsoft Office Excel?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

change the title of the column "NoOfPapers" to "OriginalNoOfPapers".  Then create a column next to it called "NoOfPapersRemaining".

Assuming the cell with "ExamName" is A1, use the following formula in C2: `=B2 - COUNTIF(Z:Z, A2)`

(this also assumes that the column called "Paper?" is in column Z... in real life change it to the correct column on your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I made four columns in row 1, Exam Name, Exam Total, Completed,Remaining. The completed column has the function

```
=Countif(B:B,A:A)
```

in roww 2, 3, 4, 5. The remaining columns are

```
D2="SUM(B2-C2)" 
D3="SUM(B3,C3)"
D4="SUM(D4,C4)"
D5="SUM(D5,C5)"
```

In row 7 I have three columns, Date Complete, Exam Name, Paper.  Exam Name must = The exact same as Cell A2:A5.  All you would need is to enter the date and the exam name and it will show the total papers done and the remaining.

This can be better but does what I believe you asked. For instance, use of conditional formatting. If there is a deadline, add a column for the date and use conditional formatting to display an approaching deadline. Freeze row 7 to see remaining after entering a lot of dates in cell A8.

Hope this helps. I'm not a pro but like learning more about Excel.